# Docker container refuses to connect to its own host ip

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-container

I am running a docker container in -it mode and am calling a shell script that should create a Postgres database at the given IP address. For example, while outside the container I would call `./create_database localhost` and it correctly creates a database connected to the localhost ip.

Within the docker container however, I run `./create_database <container name>` it correctly translates  to the host ip of the container but it returns the error `psql: connection to server at <container name> (xxx.xx.x.x), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections`.

I am not sure why it works outside the docker container but not within, is there some setup I have to do for the container ip to accept connections? I know if I want to access the container from outside I have to publish ports but that doesn’t help. I have also tried creating a network and connecting it to the container to try and run the database on the network ip but that didn’t work either.

My dockerfile is simply:

```
FROM Postgres:11
COPY . .
USER postgres
ENTRYPOINT [“bash”, “-c”]
```

My (definitely wrong) env file is:

```
POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT_LOCAL=5432
```

This is almost certainly completely incorrect but running it without an env file doesn’t change anything so I don’t think it matters.

I am running my code with `docker run -it —name database —network net —rm —env-file path/to/.env database bash`

I am rather new to docker so if I have left out any vital info let me know and I will add all the information I can.

EDIT: This is docker for linux 20.10.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways you can do this, depending on whether you want to run your setup script from the host or a container.

Either way, run the unmodified `postgres:11` image.  The `ENTRYPOINT` line you have is likely to cause problems, and your `docker run` command tries to run an interactive shell *instead of* the database server.

The first approach is to run the database container with a published port.  Then you can run your script as-is from outside a container.

```bash
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:11
./create_database localhost
```

If you're already running a PostgreSQL instance on the host and this conflicts, change the *first* port number to any other port (the second must be the standard port 5432), and change the port number in your script, maybe using the standard `PGPORT` environment variable.

```bash
docker run -d -p 12345:5432 postgres:11
export PGPORT=12345
./create_database localhost
```

The second option is to run your script in a container.  I might create a dedicated image for this

```bash
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get update --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      postgresql-client
COPY create_database /usr/local/bin
CMD echo "usage: create_database [hostname]" >&2; exit 1
```

Now you need to start both the database container and your script on the same Docker network, and use the database container's name as the host name.

```bash
docker build -t create-database .
docker create network somenet
docker run -d --name database --net somenet postgres:11
docker run --rm --net somenet create-database \
  create_database database
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker-for-mac or Docker-for-Windows 18.03+, just connect to your mysql service using the host host.docker.internal (instead of the 127.0.0.1 in your connection string).

If you are using Docker-for-Linux 20.10.0+, you can also use the host host.docker.internal if you started your Docker container with the --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway option.

Comment: I am using linux so I updated my run command to `docker run -it —name database —add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway —network net —rm —env-file path/to/.env database bash` and I get the same exact error as before. Is there something more I have to do in my docker file or something to get that to work?